# Выделение придаточных предложений

Tags: пунктуация, спп

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в данном предложении (интересует придаточное предложение)?

При этом для обеспечения эффекта избирательного переноса оказывается достаточным уже слой меди толщиной порядка 250–350 нм, а не, как это принято теоретически, от одного микрометра.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые расставлены верно. **Как это принято теоретически** является здесь вводным предложением, обособленным запятыми.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123

Comment: Спасибо большое.